# Git Hub Api receiving repeated results on search by users

Tags: javascript, rest, github

Hi I was implementing a task to get a list of users from git hub API, and my first approach does not work:

GET users?per_page=10&page=2

This URL above always returns the first page, so I tried with:

GET https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type:user&per_page=10&page=2

This second try kind of works but sometimes on a random page it returns a repeated user, how can I get the pages always with different users?

Comment: It doesn't look like you did anything wrong in your request to the API and Github's code for their search process is not clear from the documentation. Can't you just throw out the IDs which are repeated?